# having trouble position my arrows with unslider jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow, jquery-ui-slider

I was following the documentation of unslider to develop a slidershow with dots and arrows.

The dots I already have working like I want, but the arrows I´m having some issues.

I´m not having sucess align the left arrow to the left of my slider and the right arrow to the right of my slide. I already did many tests but nothing is working.

Do you know how we can do this with unslider plugin?

**What I´m trying:**
http://jsfiddle.net/jcak/RJqw8/

**My html:**

```
<section id="banner-container">

    <div class="banner">

        <ul>
           <li style="background-color:red;  height:500px;">This is another slide.</li>
            <li style="background-color:green;  height:500px;">This is another slide.</li>
           <li style="background-color:blue;  height:500px;">This is another slide.</li>   
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="unslider-arrow prev"></a>
        <a href="#" class="unslider-arrow next"></a>
    </div>

</section>
```

**My CSS:**

```
  #banner-container
    {
        width:100%;
        float:left;
    }


    .banner
    {   position: relative; 
        overflow: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .banner li
    {
        list-style:none;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
    }

    .banner ul li
    { 
        float: left;
    }

    .banner ul li img
    {   width:100%;
        height:220px;
    }
    .banner .dots 
    {   margin-left:50%;
        bottom: 10px;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        display:none;
    }

    .banner:hover .dots 
    {
        display:block;
    }

    .banner .dots li
    { 
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        border-radius: 6px;
        cursor: pointer; 
        display: inline-block;
        height: 10px;
        margin: 0 4px;
        opacity: .4; 
        text-indent: -999em; 
        -webkit-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
        -moz-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
        transition: background .5s, opacity .5s; width: 10px;
    }

    .banner .dots li.active 
    { 
        background: #fff;
        opacity: 1;
    }

.arrows .prev {
    position: relative;
    top: -136px;
}
.arrows .next {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 109px;
}
```

**My jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $('.banner').unslider({

        speed: 2000,
        delay: 2000,
        fluid: true,
        dots: true,
        arrows: true,
        pause: true


    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem your facing is that your CSS code is not adressing the < a >s because they have a different className. Two options:

#1 - Switch the classNames in your CSS file:

```
.unslider-arrow.prev {...}
.unslider-arrow.next {...}
```

#2 - Switch the classes in the < a >s to the ones you're using in your CSS file:

```
<a href="#" class="arrow prev"></a>
<a href="#" class="arrow next"></a>
```

However, when using the second option, you have to change the relations in your CSS to:

```
.arrow.prev {}
.arrow.next {}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and correctio! But even with this correction the problem still continues, but everything seems ok, I´m really not understanding where the problem is!

Comment: I just checked it myself, heres a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zc39D/2/ (ignore that the slider's not longer working, tried some things) - left and right is positioned right, but it seems that your library is mixing up things..

Comment: Thank you..it works! I didn´t put the code for the .unslider-arrow{}.

Comment: Really thanks codezombie! By the way do you know how to change the images of these arrows for images that I want? Cause unslider documentation dont talk about this!

Comment: Hey @CesarM - I'm not really sure about how to change the icons. But when you add some Text into the arrow containers you'll see that there are still arrows appearing. I suggest you should have a look at the css sheet of your slider libary, maybe they're defined in there. And when you figured out where they're set, just change them ;-) What could be interesting for you is: http://weloveiconfonts.com/

Answer (score 0):

Please check my unslider.com example html file:

```
    <!-- The HTML -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

    <head>
    <title>Unslider.com example</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="http://unslider.com/unslider.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>

        <!-- JavaScript -->

    <script type="text/javascript">

$(function() {
$('.banner').unslider({
    speed: 500,               //  The speed to animate each slide (in milliseconds)
    delay: 3000,              //  The delay between slide animations (in milliseconds)
    complete: function() {},  //  A function that gets called after every slide animation
    keys: true,               //  Enable keyboard (left, right) arrow shortcuts
    dots: true,               //  Display dot navigation
    fluid: false              //  Support responsive design. May break non-responsive designs

});
var unslider = $('.banner').unslider();

  $('.prev').click(function() {
      unslider.data('unslider').prev();
  });

  $('.next').click(function() {
      unslider.data('unslider').next();
  });
  return false;
});
</script>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <style type="text/css">

* { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.banner {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;
top: 50px;
/*z-index: -1;*/

font-size: 18px;
line-height: 24px;
text-align: center;

color: #FFFFFF;
text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);

background: #FFFFFF;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}
.banner ul {
list-style: none;
width: 300%;
}
.banner ul li {
display: block;
float: left;

min-height: 500px;

-o-background-size: 100% 100%;
-ms-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;

box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.banner .inner {
padding: 360px 0 110px;

float: left;
vertical-align:-100px;
}

.banner h1, .banner h2 {

font-size: 40px;
line-height: 52px;
color: #fff;
}

.banner .btn {
display: inline-block;
margin: 25px 0 0;
padding: 9px 22px 7px;
clear: both;

color: #fff;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
border : rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) solid 2px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
.banner .btn:hover {
background : rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
}
.banner .btn:active {
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
-moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
-ms-filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
-o-filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
filter: drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5));
}

.banner .btn, .banner .dot {
-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
-moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
-ms-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
-o-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3));
}

.banner .dots {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 20px;
width: 100%;
}
.banner .dots li {
display: inline-block;

width: 10px;
height: 10px;
line-height: 10px;
margin: 0 4px;

text-indent: -999em;


border: 2px solid #fff;
border-radius: 6px;

cursor: pointer;
opacity: .4;

-webkit-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
-moz-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
}
.banner .dots li.active {
background: #fff;
opacity: 1;
}




.unslider-arrow {
  font-family: Expressway;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3d3d3d;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
  padding: 0 20px 5px 20px;
}

.next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  right: 0  
}

.prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  right: 90 /* change to left:0; if u wanna have arrow on left side */ 
}
</style>
     </head>
    <!-- Body of HTML document -->

    <body>
        <div class="slider">
        <div class="banner">
          <ul>
          <li style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/');">
            <div class="inner">
              <h1>Some h1 text</h1>
             <p>smaller p text</p>

                <a class="btn" href="http://www.yourlink.com">Hyperlink</a>
            </div>
          </li>

          <li style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/');">
            <div class="inner">
              <h1>Some h1 text</h1>
             <p>smaller p text</p>

              <a class="btn" href="http://www.yourlink.com">Hyperlink</a>
              </div>
              </li>

           <li style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/');">
             <div class="inner">
              <h1>Some h1 text</h1>
             <p>smaller p text</p>

              <a class="btn" href="http://www.yourlink.com">Hyperlink</a>
              </div>
          </li>

          <li style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/');">
          <div class="inner">
              <h1>Some h1 text</h1>
             <p>smaller p text</p>

              <a class="btn" href="http://www.yourlink.com">Hyperlink</a>
            </div>
          </li>
      </ul>


        </div>
          <a href="#" class="unslider-arrow prev">&larr;</a>
          <a href="#" class="unslider-arrow next">&rarr;</a>
        </div>
   </body>  

</html>
```